# How to add nodes dynamically to a RichTree in Oracle ADF?

Tags: java, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

i've been looking for every corner of internet this question, and i didn't have success to find a solution, i made some examples with RichPanelAccordion but i haven't find some equivalent

This is my code for RichPanelAccordion

I create the Header of panel

```
List<UIComponent> child = getPh3().getChildren();
RichPanelAccordion GCHeader = new RichPanelAccordion();
GCHeader.setId("PanelMenuHeader");
GCHeader.setStyleClass("HeaderGCMenu");
GCHeader.setShortDesc("Menu");
GCHeader.setChildCreation("immediate");
```

Then add nodes or childs to the Header

```
RichShowDetailItem PBR = new RichShowDetailItem();
PBR.setText("Child Node");
PBR.setIcon("/Images/config_icon.png");
PBR.setStyleClass("ChildGCMenu");
GCHeader.getChildren().add(PBR);
```

How can i do this with RichTree instead?

```
RichTree rt = new RichTree();
```

Im using JDeveloper

Answer (score 0):

For `RichTree` UIComponent you can add a column as a child.

```
  RichTree rt = new RichTree();

  RichColumn column1= new RichColumn();
  column1.setDisplayIndex(0);
  column1.setFilterable(false);      
  column1.setHeaderText("Column Header");
  column1.setSortable(true);

  RichOutputText op1 = new RichOutputText();
  op1.setValue("value123");

  column.getChildren().add(op1); 
  rt.getChildren().add(column1);
```

There are many more attributes, components that you can add to your column component.
Hope this answer can act as a pointer.

> https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E68505_01/adf/api-reference-faces/oracle/adf/view/rich/component/rich/data/RichTree.html
>
> https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12211/adf/api-reference-faces/oracle/adf/view/rich/component/rich/data/RichColumn.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately is not working, still appear "No data to display", i added it just like your example

Comment: Is the "No data to display" appearing instead of the value123 of the children node ? Or for the whole table ?

Comment: The whole tree.

Answer (score 0):

To programmatically add data to ADF tree widget, you will fist have to prepare your own instance of

```
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.model.ChildPropertyTreeModel
```

Here's the [constructor documentation](https://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/trinidad-api/apidocs/org/apache/myfaces/trinidad/model/ChildPropertyTreeModel.html)

```
  /**
   * Creates a TreeModel
   * @param instance The Collection of root nodes of this tree.
   * This can be a List or array of beans (or Maps).
   * This instance is first converted into a CollectionModel (see
   * {@link ModelUtils#toCollectionModel}).
   * @param childProperty This property will be used to get at the child Lists
   * from each bean (or Map). Bean rules will be used to find a getter method
   * that matches this property. If each node is a Map, this property will be
   * passed in to the Map's get method to get the child List. 
   */
  public ChildPropertyTreeModel(Object instance, String childProperty)
```

Once you have populated your TreeModel, you just have to setValue this on the [RichTree](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E68505_01/adf/api-reference-faces/oracle/adf/view/rich/component/rich/data/RichTree.html) instance.

The documentation for [ChildPropertyTreeModel](https://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/trinidad-api/apidocs/org/apache/myfaces/trinidad/model/ChildPropertyTreeModel.html) has some useful tips on how to construct a tree model using simple POJO's

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i've tried do that, but always throw me error NullPointerException when tried to load the tree, you have an example about that code?

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you paste the stack trace